# Compare two columns with millions of records in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management

How do I compare two columns returned from MySQL db tables containing millions of records each? I'm basically comparing phone numbers from TableA and TableB. Numbers in TableA are checked against numbers in TableB and duplicate numbers are deleted if found. I have used `array_intersect($array1, $array2)` since the returned numbers are stored in arrays. This returns the duplicate numbers but the problem is that it consumes too much memory and takes forever to execute.

Is there any way of doing this without comsuming much memory? Numbers contained in TableA and TableB are over 10 million each.

Comment: compare on the mysql side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query, that will return all numbers that are present both in TableA and in TableB:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.Number
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
     ON TableA.Number = TableB.Number
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to read that much data into memory.  Why not just do this all in SQL?

If you want to find all records in Table A that don't exist in Table B just do this:

```
SELECT a.field
FROM
  table_a AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b AS b
    ON a.field = b.field
WHERE b.field IS NULL
```

If you want to delete all rows from A that don't have matches in B, you can easily do this in SQL as well:

```
DELETE a
FROM
  table_a AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b AS b
    ON a.field = b.field
WHERE b.field IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. Reastically, TableB records(numbers) are returned by REST api which is checked with existing TableA numbers in local db.

Comment: @BenjaminIgbokwe You are receiving a REST response with millions of records in it?

Comment: that's right, JSON response. So my problem is reducing the amount of time taken to intersect which our db result which is stored in array as well.

Comment: @BenjaminIgbokwe That is just crazy.  Why would one want to pass that much data in an API call? It sounds like you have more fundamental issue in your system, as even if each record consumes only a handful of bytes, you are talking about taking up several MB in memory to store that data, plus a similar size of data coming in from the DB that must be held in memory, plus you have some amount of time spent just reading in the REST response and DB result set into memory.  I really hope this process is not one that must run regularly with any sort of reasonable execution time.